# How to input menu and show the data without save on the database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

[image: form image]

I have a form input menu and quantity here (yellow line on pic). When I submit that the data is shown on the table (red line on pic) but is not saved on database (show only). Then I have a save button in the bottom (not yet on the picture because it is cropped) that will store the data that we have input earlier (which appear in the table).

How do I get the input from the menu to only appear in the table but later (after press the save data) is fed into the database?

I'm using CodeIgniter, AJAX and jQuery.

Comment: Don't you have some code that go along with this picture?

Comment: I think you should use HTML5 sessionStorage that will save you data into the browser memory. So you can access and show data in the table. And whenever you want to post it into the server it will be easily accessible.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery to show input field content in table, here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/y2vmqL06/.

```
$("input").on('keyup change', function(){
  if($(this).val() != ""){
    $("#container").text($(this).val());
  }else{
    $("#container").text("");
  }
});
```

On submit you can use php to do normal database operations

Comment: yes like that,but i'll input and show much of data, an example is i'm input the name and age(name : jason, age : 22), then submit(show in the table). and then i'm trying input different name and age(name: daniel, age : 18) and submit(show in the table without without deleting previous data) so later the result will be like : jason 22 daniel 18 and will continue to grow when I input new data

Comment: You can use js/jquery to add new element without deleting previous one, check this code https://jsfiddle.net/y2vmqL06/3/

Comment: yes sir, but that only showed one of data
i'll input much row of data, but without erasing data previously which i've submit, 
please help

Comment: Same logic can be used to create an container when one of the input field has data, and can destroy it if all field are empty, check this code https://jsfiddle.net/y2vmqL06/4/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use multiple forms.

After Clicking on submit button in the first form pass your values in the second form and display them and in second form after clicking on save pass them to save into database.

It is just like the procedure mention in the code shown below:

```
<html>
   <form action="yourfilepath.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="first_value">
       <input type="text" name="second_value">
       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
   <form action="savedbfile.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="fst_value" value=" <?php 
        if(isset($_POST["first_value"]))
            echo  $_POST["first_value"]); 
        ?> " >
       <input type="text" name="sec_value" value=" <?php 
        if(isset($_POST["second_value"]))
            echo  $_POST["second_value"]); 
        ?> " >
       <input type="submit" value="save">
   </form>
</html>
```

Comment: yes like that,but i'll input and show much of data, an example is i'm input the name and age(name : jason, age : 22), then submit(show in the table). and then i'm trying input different name and age(name: daniel, age : 18) and submit(show in the table without without deleting previous data)
so later the result will be like :
jason 22
daniel 18 


and will continue to grow when I input new data

Answer (score 0):

Add data in temporary table first. And after click on save you can move data from temporary table to permanent table.